# SQL to LINQ with outer apply

Tags: c#, linq

I am not able convert sql to linq because of outer apply

```
select * from dbo.Table1 l
inner join dbo.Table2 d on d.LoanId = l.Id
inner join dbo.Cash cOriginal on cOriginal.DealId = d.Id and cOriginal.IsOriginal = 1
outer apply (select top 1 * from dbo.Cash cActive
             where cActive.DealId = d.ID and cActive.IsOriginal = 0
             order by cActive.CreatedOn desc) cActiveRes
```

I am started something like this:

```
var q = from x in _repo.Queryable<Table1>()
 join Table2 in _repo.Queryable<Table2>() on x.Id equals Table2.LoanId
 join cOriginal in _repo.Queryable<Cash>() on Table2.Id equals 
                                                           cOriginal.DealId
 // now Outer Apply should come?
 // fActive in _repo.Queryable<Cash>()
```

Comment: Did any of the following help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it to run your SQL query directly letting EF to materialize the result. It might look like this (depending on version of EF you use):

```
var result = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_repo).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Table1>(
               @"SELECT your query here");
```